# Delete a custom post function value

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm having an issue with custom functions at the moment, once a value has been added to the database I can not delete the value, what's the best way to solve this?

Basically I've created a custom post type for a games database, when adding a game there are several custom post functions; game developer, publisher, review score and a review URL, now if I enter a test URL it will save that but when I try to delete it, it still appears and wont save the deleted value.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
function display_games_database_meta_box( $games_database ) {
// Retrieve information from the game
$game_publisher = esc_html( get_post_meta( $games_database->ID, 'game_publisher', true     ) );
$game_developer = esc_html( get_post_meta( $games_database->ID, 'game_developer', true ) );
$game_rating = intval( get_post_meta( $games_database->ID, 'game_rating', true ) );
$game_review_link = esc_html( get_post_meta( $games_database->ID, 'game_review_link', true ) );
$game_release = esc_html( get_post_meta( $games_database->ID, 'game_release', true ) );
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%">Game Publisher</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="80" name="games_database_game_publisher" value="<?    php echo $game_publisher; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%">Game Developer</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="80" name="games_database_game_developer" value="<?php echo $game_developer; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 150px">Game Rating</td>
        <td>
            <select style="width: 100px" name="games_database_rating">
            <option value="No Score">No Score</option>
            <?php
            // Generate all items of drop-down list
            for ( $rating = 10; $rating >= 1; $rating -- ) {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rating; ?>" <?php echo selected( $rating, $game_rating ); ?>>
                <?php echo $rating; ?>/10<?php } ?>

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%">Review Link (Use the full URL)</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="80" name="games_database_review_link" value="<?php echo $game_review_link; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%">Game Release Date (Format: June 26th 2013)</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="80" name="games_database_game_release" value="<?    php echo $game_release; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
<?php
// Adds and saves the game to the database
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_games_database_fields', 10, 4 );
function add_games_database_fields( $games_database_id, $games_database ) {
// Check post type for games
if ( $games_database->post_type == 'games_database' ) {
    // Store data in post meta table if present in post data
    if ( isset( $_POST['games_database_game_publisher'] ) && $_POST['games_database_game_publisher'] != '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $games_database_id, 'game_publisher', $_POST['games_database_game_publisher'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['games_database_game_developer'] ) && $_POST['games_database_game_developer'] != '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $games_database_id, 'game_developer', $_POST['games_database_game_developer'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['games_database_rating'] ) && $_POST['games_database_rating'] != '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $games_database_id, 'game_rating', $_POST['games_database_rating'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['games_database_review_link'] ) && $_POST['games_database_review_link'] != '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $games_database_id, 'game_review_link', $_POST['games_database_review_link'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['games_database_game_release'] ) && $_POST['games_database_game_release'] != '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $games_database_id, 'game_release', $_POST['games_database_game_release'] );
    }
}
}
```

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Post your code please and explain what you are doing in more detail.

Comment: @s_ha_dum done :)

Comment: I believe when you say "custom post functions" you mean "custom post meta". Yes?

Comment: @GhostToast yeah sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is checking to see if anything "is set" before proceeding to update, and also that it isn't an empty string. Remove the "if" portions of your update statements, or better yet, put an "else" after to [delete post meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta) if it is empty.

#### Example:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['games_database_game_release'] ) && $_POST['games_database_game_release'] != '' ) {
    update_post_meta( $games_database_id, 'game_release', $_POST['games_database_game_release'] );
} else {
    delete_post_meta( $games_database_id, 'game_release');
}
```

Comment: Okay so this is my code now so I've added that to my code but it still isn't working?

Comment: do I need to add the } else { line after each if?

Comment: ^^ Yes, each `if` needs an `else` on the same pattern as the example.